# Visual Studio 2017: Custom Code Snippets Work, but Files are Missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, code-snippets

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 Professional on Windows 10. Long ago I made some custom code snippets, and today I wanted to amend them. But while they work perfectly fine in Visual Studio, the files themselves seem to be long gone. They don't appear in the Code Snippets Manager, right-click -> Insert Snippet, etc., and as far as I can tell through searching, they're nowhere on disk.

But if I type my snippet shortcut, it works perfectly fine. Where is Visual Studio pulling them from, if they appear to not be loaded or included anywhere else? I've searched the Documents path where custom snippets are stored as well as the path within Visual Studio's Program Files. I even checked the Visual Studio 2015 and 2019 folders I have on here, but these custom snippets are nowhere to be found.

EDIT: These are absolutely custom snippets, not built-in ones. A couple examlpes are `pvt` ("public void test") that I use for stubbing out a unit test for NUnit. I have a similar one for XUnit (`pvx`). `pvtstr` (testing with a string input) is another.

Comment: The only logical explanation is that you got into the habit of using the built-in snippets that VS provides.  Improve the question by documenting the shortcut you use.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my post to clarify that these are absolutely *not* built-in/default snippets.

Comment: Do they still work if you disconnect internet? If they do, they certainly are stored on disk *somewhere*. Also, can you find the location on disk of *new* snippets that you add?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS 2019 and my snippets for c# are in:

```
C:\Users\ccati\OneDrive\Documents 1\Visual Studio 2019\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets
```

The 2017 snippets were in:

```
C:\Users\ccati\OneDrive\Visual Studio 2017\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets
```

Basically they were in the Documents folder...In my case, the Documents Folder is protected by OneDrive.

Answer (score -2):

The only situation where I have noticed similar behavior is when I have edited a code snippet file. After an edit I sometimes had to restart Visual Studio in order to use the updated code snippet. If you have not already, try to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry. My issue isn't that custom snippets aren't working in VS. It's that they *are* working in VS, but the source files for my custom snippets are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I guess that some of the same caching mechanisms might be at work here so you might be able to resolve it with the same actions.

Answer (score -2):

You can edit your snippets file in visual code :

**ctrl + shift + p**

Type **snippets**

And Select **Preferences: Configure User Snippets**

Now, you should see the location of your file on top of the editor, in the breadcrumb (if not, go to view, **Show Breadcrumb**).

Comment: This one worked for me, can you explain what result did you get with this solution ?

Comment: The OP asked for Visual Studio not Visual Studio Code